# Closing console application after completion from Python

Tags: python, windows, command-line, batch-file

I have an exe file that I have to call with several parameters, and for this purpose I use a bat file. After I execute bat file command prompt does not close, but wait for me to press a key. Now I have to run this exe several times, and for this I want to run a script that will do it for me.

```
i = 0
for path in Paths
    outout = codecs.open('runExe.bat', 'w')
    output.write(PathToExe + " -param1" + " -param2 " + param2Val[0] + " -param3 " + param3Val[0] + " -param4 " + param4Val[0] + " -param5 param5Val")
    output.close()
    subprocess.call(["regsvr32.exe", path, "-u", "-s"])
    subprocess.call(["regsvr32.exe", path, "-s"])
    subprocess.call("runExe.bat")
    i + = 1
```

where param3Val, param4Val, param5Val are lists with values for related command prompt parameters.
When I call this bat file, everything works perfectly for the first fun of exe, but after it executes, command promt waits for my respond. When I press any key, it closes and then exe file starts with different parameters.
So I want to eliminate with key-pressing thing. I tried to put "exit" to the end of the bat file, but it did not work. How can I close command prompt window from script, when exe finishes working?
Thanks in advance!
[image]
Upd1: sarmold's way of doing thing works fine, but I think this it is exe (console application) that is waiting for my response.  Smth in exe file prevents console window from closing, but I do not have access to sources. How can I close it's window after it executes?

Upd2: I have tried to add "shell" call after subprocess.call, but this does not seem to work either, still have to respond to the console manually :(

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate("Command Prompt")
shell.SendKeys("cls(ENTER)")
```

Comment: +1, but I'd like to mention two things.  It is not recommended to use CamelCase for variables like Paths and PathToExe: it is best to either use either lowercase letters, or uppercase letters (for constants).  I would recommend that you check out PEP 8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  Furthermore, you might consider using the usual form `" ".join(PathToExe, '-param1 -param2', param2Val[0], '-param3',…)` instead of concatenating many strings that contain spaces together.

Comment: Does Windows support piping?  if yes, maybe you could send a character to `regsvr32.exe ` that would be like you pressing a key?  Under Unix, you can do `echo | <cmd>` and `<cmd>` receives a newline character.

Comment: Thanks EOL, that for pep link, will read it. Hm, thanks, I will try to search for piping solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible approaches here:

1. Make only a single `bat` file that contains all your commands, including the `regsvr32.exe` commands, and execute that.
2. Have the Python script do everything for you.

For the first approach, use the [`"a"`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) open mode to *append* to the batch file. (Perhaps delete it at script start.) Write the contents of your three commands to the batch file within the loop -- so you wind up with a *long* batch file that includes all the commands you need.

Then call the `subprocess.call()` command once, outside the loop, at the end of the script, to run the entire thing.

For the second approach, remove *all* the batch-file writing and run your `PathToExe` using Python's `subprocess.call()`. It's almost as simple as deleting all lines that work with `output`, but change `output.write()` to `subprocess.call()` -- and obviously, fiddle with the contents a little bit so they work for `subprocess.call()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this in a way that launches a command prompt every time you run `runExe.bat`? It shouldn't *necessarily* wait for you to close the console, but since it does, try running your script with `subprocess.call("cmd /C runExe.bat")`.

@Arnold is right, though: It's better to simplify your set-up and (imho) just let python handle everything.